# How can I cause a newly created .csv file to be downloaded to the user?

Tags: node.js, csv

I have created a button on my website, that when clicked will create a `.csv` file. What I want is for this file to be downloaded to the user immediately after the file has been created. Here is what I have so far:

```
var data = ...; // stuff
var fields = ...; // stuff
json2csv({ data: data, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    fs.writeFile('test.csv', csv, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
       console.log('file saved');
       // now, download this file to the user. How?
    });
});
```

The `.csv` file is created, but I want the file to then be immediately downloaded to the user. Ideally, the .csv file would be streamed directly to the user without it ever being saved on my server, but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using express, you can use [sendFile](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile). Assuming your code has access to the `response` object, you can send the file like this:

```
var data = ...; // stuff
var fields = ...; // stuff
json2csv({ data: data, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    fs.writeFile('test.csv', csv, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved');

        var options = {
            root: __dirname
        };

        res.sendFile('test.csv', options, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(err.status).end();
            }
            else {
                console.log('Sent:', fileName);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As for sending the file without saving it to your server, you can do that setting the `Content-Disposition` header:

```
var data = ...; // stuff
var fields = ...; // stuff
json2csv({ data: data, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    res.set({
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.csv',
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
    });
    res.send(csv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a HTTP response with the appropriate file type and send it if you are not using Express:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
});

res.write(csv); // or csv.pipe(res) if csv is a readable stream
res.end();
```